# JavaFX- how to save the selected from ChoiceBox

Tags: java, javafx, save

How can I save/get the selected from the ChoiceBox

This is how I made the ChoiceBox:

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
.
.
List boxList = new LinkedList<String>();
boxList.add("Yes");
boxList.add("No");
ChoiceBox choBoxAddLR = new ChoiceBox(FXCollections.observableList(boxList));
grid.add(choBoxAddLR, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get the Selected item like this:

```
choBoxAddLR.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

or you add an listener to it:

```
 choBoxAddLR .getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty()
    .addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
      public void changed(ObservableValue ov, String value, String new_value) {
        // ...
      }
    });
```